# Get a hold of a FormControl instance by querying a component's template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a custom `FormFieldComponent` that encapsulates the HTML and error display logic for a form field:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">{{label}}</label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>  <!-- Will display the field -->
      <!-- Here, put error display logic -->
    </div>
  `
})
export class FormFieldComponent {
  @Input() label: string;  // Field label
  @Input() theControl: FormControl;  // Current form control, required to display errors
}
```

In `FormFieldComponent`, I need an instance of the FormControl to display errors.

My form then looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  ...
  <field label="Title" [theControl]="myForm.get('title')">
    <input type="text" formControlName="title">
  </field>
  ...
</form>
```

But I'm not entirely satisfied with the above code. As you can see, I am specifying the field's key in two locations: in the `[theControl]` input property and in the `formControlName` directive.

The code would be more concise if I could just write:

```
<field label="Title">
  <input type="text" formControlName="title">
</field>
```

Notice how the `[theControl]` input property is gone. The `FieldComponent` should be able to get a hold of the FormControl instance it contains, but how?

I have tried using the `@ContentChildren` decorator to query the component's template for FormControl directives, but it doesn't work:

```js
export class FormFieldComponent {
  @ContentChildren(FormControlDirective) theControl: any;
}
```

Another option would be to pass the field's key as an input to `FormFieldComponent` and then let the component use that key to:

- Programmatically apply the `formControlName` directive to the field it contains.
- Get a hold of its parent `<form>`, access the corresponding FormGroup instance, and extract the FormControl instance from that.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  I have many reactive forms in my app and never once used [control], I only use formControlName.

Comment: @John: `[control]` is not an Angular directive, it's just the name I gave to my input property. I'll rename `[control]` to `[theControl]` to make it more obvious. So, do you know how a component can get a hold of the FormControl instances that appear in its template?

Comment: Can't you add #formInstance  to the <form> tag?

Comment: My question is why do you want to do that as long as you can create your own custom input by implementing `ControlValueAccessor` ?

Comment: Love to see that solution n00dl3

Comment: done @JohnBaird ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### short answer: You can't

You just can't. (Well, maybe be you can but it will be hacky !)

### long answer: you can't, but...

`FormControl` is not injectable. Directives are injectable, but, you would have to deal with `formControlName`,`ngModel`,`formControl`, etc and they wouldn't be accessible from the wrapping component but its children...

For your case you could try with `@ContentChildren(FormControlName) theControl: any;` as there is no `FormControlDirective` implied in your code, but you wouldn't be able to access the `FormControl` anyway (property `_control` is internal, soo it would be a hack)...

So you should stick to managing your errors from the component dealing with the `FormGroup`.

**BUT** if you want to display a custom input (that won't display error message as is but will be able to show this input is in error state (the host element will get the `ng-valid`, `ng-invalid` classes, so it's just a matter of style), you can do this by implementing [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html).

> A bridge between a control and a native element.
>
> A ControlValueAccessor abstracts the operations of writing a new value to a DOM element representing an input control.

It means directives/components implementing this interface can be used with `ngModel`, `formControl`,etc...

eg: `<my-component [(ngModel)]="foo"></my-component>`

it is not the exact reproduction of your problem, but this implementation solved the same kind of problem for me :

```js
export const INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: "field",
  template: `<!--put anything you want in your template-->
            <label>{{label}}</label>
            <input #input (input)="onChange($event.target.value)" (blur)="onTouched()" type="text">`,
  styles: [],
  providers: [INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild("input")
  input: ElementRef;
  @Input()
  label:string;
  onChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer) { }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? "" : value;
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this.input.nativeElement, "value", normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
      this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this.input.nativeElement, "disabled", isDisabled);
  }
}
```

then you can just :

```
<field label="Title" formControlName="title"></field>
```

Comment: @n00dl3: thanks for a very detailed and clear answer. I'm curious: How do you handle fields other than `<input type="text">`, specifically `<select>`, `<textarea>`... fields?

Comment: Well you can create a component by input type. if you want to call a single component for every field type, you can create a wrapper with a `type` `@Input()` and an `ngSwitch` in the template (it should implements `ControlValueAccessor` too and call children method via `@ViewChild()` references). For the select (same for radios) it's a bit more complex, because you will need to create a `my-select` and a `my-option` component, injecting `my-select` in its children. (to be continued)...

Comment: You can take a look at the code in the [angular repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/2.2.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives), especialy the `*_value_accessor.ts` files. but you won't get help for radios/select in those files as they are using internal properties and methods (but what I told you in the previous comment works well, I did it for radios, if you need help for that specifically (injection of parent, etc...) I'm affraid it is out of the scope of this question)...
and now... BEER TIME!!!!!!

Comment: @AngularFrance need more help ?

Answer (score 10):

You can get ahold of the Form Control Name instance via:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  templateUrl: './field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field.component.scss']
})
export class FieldComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input()
  public label: string;

  @ContentChild(FormControlName)
  public controlName: FormControlName;

  public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.controlName.control);
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works great for me.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if things have changed, but I found a seemingly supported way to do this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10076)

Essentially, you can use the `@ContentChild` decorator and depending on your form control or how you have it linked into your template control, use the proper directive as the selector for the decorator.

For example, if I am projecting an input that uses the case as you have, the [formControl], you are in the same boat as the author of that GitHub ticket.  For me, I was using the 'formGroupName' directive, and as confusing as it was, the correct usage of the directive for that worked out to be `@ContentChild(FormControlName) control;`

HTH!